# Use mockito to mock method with Object parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method :

```
public class Sender{
  public Object send(Object param){
    Object x;
    .....
    return (x);
  }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for this method using Mockito such that the return type value is based on the class type of the paramter. So I did this:

```
when(sender.send(Matchers.any(A.class))).thenReturn(value1);
when(sender.send(Matchers.any(B.class))).thenReturn(value2);
```

but the return value irrespective of the parameter class type is always value 2. How do it get this to return value 1 for class A type argument and value 2 for class B type argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `when(sender.send(Matchers.any(A.class))).thenReturn(value1);`

Mockito will try to mock a method with signature `send(A param)`, not `send(Object param)`.

What you need is to return a different value base on the class of you parameter. You need to use Answers for this.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
    if(invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0].getClass() instanceof A) {
        return value1;
    }
    if(invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0].getClass() instanceof B) {
        return value2;
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected type");
    }
}).when(mock).send(Mockito.anyObject());
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, but too lazy to write :-)

Comment: @noscreenname Ahh! Can you convert this to not using the lambda expression please? I understand the intent but unable to replicate it.

Comment: @Sherlock123 I could, but so could you if you look up Mockito.doAnswer() documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

A couple options:

1. Don't use `any`. Use the instance of `A` or `B` you're using in the test.
2. Use an `Answer` object, which would allow you to specify what to return.